# Libraries for interfacing with the GPIO

Tags: gpio

What libraries are available for interfacing with the GPIO?

Comment: not a complete list, but [here](http://codeandlife.com/2015/03/25/raspberry-pi-2-vs-1-gpio-benchmark/) are a few - although I think this question will be closed, as list-type questions tend not to work well on the stack sites, as there will be a never-ending stream of answers

Answer (score 16):

I'm going to interpret what I think you might be asking more broadly as "How can I control GPIO from userland?"

A very nice way to get started using GPIO is using the `/sys` filesytem. You can do it all from the command line.

For example,

```
cd sys/class/gpio
echo 0 > export
cd gpio0
echo high > direction
```

More documentation is in [linux/Documentation/gpio.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4.2/Documentation/gpio.txt#L576).

Comment: Does this work with every OS?

Comment: This is linux-specific.

Comment: Are there any tutorials that use this method? I have only seen libraries (mainly the python one).

Comment: Added a link to the docs.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a library as per the request of the OP.

Comment: The other answers for this question are much better - this answer does not answer the question about libraries.

Answer (score 13):

There is one that I've found [here](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/). I haven't had the chance to test it, as my Pi hasn't arrived. It does, however, look assuring. There's even a forum thread [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=7143) that professes promising payoff. If you want a down-to-the-basics C example using standard libraries, there's one [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Driving_Example_.28C.29) from eLinux.

Comment: What was your experiece of this library, then?

Answer (score 11):

[RPi.GPIO](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) is a Python package for GPIO control.

[This tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_NvDTZIaS4) shows the basic usage of the package.

Answer (score 2):

[quick2wire](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-python-api) can be used by regular users (not root):

> ### Quick2Wire Python API
>
> A Python library for controlling the hardware attached to the Raspberry Pi's header pins, [without running as the root user](http://quick2wire.com/articles/working-safely-with-your-pi/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MarkBooth : "the essential part of the answer" is "**can be used by regular users**" unlike other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Wiring PI](http://wiringpi.com/) and it works really great. I use it with language C and had no problems so far. It is easy to understand and simple to handle.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm answering a question that is years old, but there is one that hasn't been mentioned yet:  gpiozero.
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

It should already be installed on new versions of Raspbian. You can also install it on other versions of Linux.
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple to control the GPIO ports in any language as shown on [http://elinux.org](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Driving_Example_.28Shell_script.29), so I believe that you actually do not need a framework for the direct control.

You need to know which additional features you expect of a framework, like

- Remote control via a browser
- A pretty browser UI or maybe a standalone program
- Automatic timebased control ([cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs)

I ended up writing a framework for myself: [Control GPIO ports over HTTP and with cron jobs](https://bitbucket.org/sbub/raspberry-pi-gpio-web-control) which perfectly fits my needs. I wanted to have something for home-automation. So I needed cron jobs and a JSON web interface to run a native app on my iPhone. Therefore I did not write a browser UI. I believe it would also be good for an alarm system.

I did not find a (complete) list of frameworks yet. There are some mentioned on the forum of raspberrypi.org.

Answer (score 1):

Pi4J allows you to control the GPIO pins using Java.
I'm not sure how it works but there's an explanation at http://pi4j.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Johny-Five](http://johnny-five.io/) is quite easy to use for those familiar with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) or JavaScript.
See http://johnny-five.io/examples/raspi-io/

```sh
npm install johnny-five raspi-io
```

```js
var five = require("johnny-five");
var Raspi = require("raspi-io").RaspiIO;
var board = new five.Board({
  io: new Raspi()
});

board.on("ready", function() {
  var led = new five.Led("P1-13");
  led.blink();
});
```

Specially useful for Pi projects controlling GPIO through a Web server