# Where is the PWM pin located exactly on the board?

Tags: pwm

Can someone point me to exactly where the PWM pin is on the board and how I can hook this thing up visually as I'm totally lost as to what I would need to make this run. Also what is the snippet of code needed to make it pulse every 2 seconds.

Comment: http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals Not sure what you mean by pwm pin.

Comment: It's pin called GPIO18. But since you need one pulse every 2 seconds, you don't seem to need PWM at all. I'm not even sure it can be used with such a small frequency. You can, however, easily do this in software, swapping regular GPIO in every two seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals), GPIO pin 18 supports PWM.

To control it from the shell without root permissions, you need to install the [wiringPi](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/download-and-install/) library. Take a look at the [gpio docs](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/) or the man page for more information:

```
man gpio
```

In short: First set the mode of pin 18 to PWM:

```
gpio -g mode 18 pwm
```

Then you can set the pin to a PWM value between 0 and 1023:

```
gpio -g pwm 18 512
```

However, as Krzysztof already noted, you probably don't need PWM if you just want to send a short pulse. You could use a regular pin and simply turn it on and off every 2 seconds.

```
gpio -g mode 17 out
gpio -g write 17 1
gpio -g write 17 0
```

You could also control it from a program, e.g. a Python script. You should find information about this in the [docs](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals).

All this is untested, but should work. If you have more problems, feel free to comment or look at the  or the manpage.

A related question can be found here: [Can I use the GPIO for pulse width modulation (PWM)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/298/can-i-use-the-gpio-for-pulse-width-modulation-pwm)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use PWM to control a servo connected to GPIO Pin 18 on an RPi 0W (Same [pin setup](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2/README.md) as the 2x20 header on A+/B+/Pi 2B/Pi 3B). The servo listed the following controls:

> Voltage : 3V to 6V DC
>
> Position "0" (1.5ms pulse) is middle, "90" (~2ms pulse) is all the way
>   to the right, "-90" (~1ms pulse) is all the way to the left.

Here is a bash script to control the servo using the pigs cli tool:

```
sudo apt install pigpio
sudo pigpiod
pigs s 18 2000 #Right (gpio pin 18)
pigs s 18 1500 #Middle
pigs s 18 1500 #Left
#Script to sweep thru the full range
DELAY=0.01 STEP=10
for i in $(seq 1000 $STEP 2000); do pigs s 18 $i; sleep $DELAY; done; 
sleep .5; 
for i in $(seq 2000 "-$STEP" 1000); do pigs s 18 $i; sleep $DELAY; done;
```

Instead of a CLI tool you can also use pigpio libraries for [Python or C](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29797/40461)