# Share input between 2 RPis

Tags: networking

I have Two or more RPIs where one is places in a different building with a few buttons.
The other has to get the value from the first and play a sound if one of the buttons is pushed on the first.

How do I get value that a button is pushed from the first RPI on the Second RPI? I'm new here.

Currently using Python. They are connected to my local Network and plaining to have more RPIs connected in different buildings.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Related (but imo not a dupe as other solutions might apply): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29784/19949

Comment: You should look at publishing the button status from the first RPi on an MQTT topic that the second RPi can subscribe to. One RPi will need to run a broker like Mosquitto, RabbitMQ or HiveMQ. https://www.hivemq.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-mqtt/

Comment: @David Jr Wollmann, Ah, let me see.  Your following comment is a bit too vague: "multiple Rpis on multple buildings LAN".  Is you LAN Wifi or Cat5? If Wifi, are they 500m+ apart? Your question starts with buttons.  Will the buttons become text messages, and streaming audios and video?  If you start with python, then you can consider python modules http, ftp, tcp, utp, mqtt, ... If you are new to GPIO, I would suggest to start newbie exercises on UART to warm up, such as this: (1) Open two serial ports, Port 1, using on Rpi board serial TxD, RxD pins. Port 2 using USB to serial, / to continue,

Comment: @David Jr Wollmann, I start with the stupid, point to point, non many to many wired, short distance (100m) network. But once you have gained some newbie knowledge nad skills, you can "easily" upgrade your stupid wire serial network to a humble Bluetooth wireless point to point, but at least one to many network (ok still 10m PAN).  But you only need one cheapy (US$1 or 2)  "Bluetooth serial module" to enable your Rpi to talk to an Android smart phone (with Bluetooh serial app) to transfer text messages at low speed.  Of course you can always upgrade, and 5G is coming to (my) town 2020Q2, ...

Comment: I'm using Enet Cat6 through a switch with router, I can get the button to work on one RPI, now I need to send that value to the Main RPI. Will include multiple RPI's sending button clicks to the Main RPI.

Answer (score 1):

Use a RF422MHz module or NRF Module with both pi. Use the HT12D and HT12E as decoder encoder for networking. This is how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module allows you to control and monitor the GPIO of multiple Pis over a network.

Each networked Pi must be running the pigpio [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html).

You can use `raspi-config` on Raspbian to enable the pigpio daemon (`Interfacing Options -> Remote GPIO Enable/Disable remote access to GPIO pins`).

The controlling Python script can be running on a Windows, Mac, or Linux machine, actually any machine which supports Python.

The same functionality is available from the Raspberry Pi Foundation's [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Python module.  See the chapters on Remote GPIO.

All the tools are pre-installed on full Raspbian builds.  For Raspbian Lite you would need to download pigpio using the following commands.

`sudo apt install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio`