# How is it possible to make hardware pwm more precise?

Tags: pwm

I started building a drone (quad) and i was wondering if i will have any problems with the accuracy of the signal i am going to send to the esc's. according to mr booth in [Can I use the GPIO for pulse width modulation (PWM)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/298/can-i-use-the-gpio-for-pulse-width-modulation-pwm) under "What if I need multiple hardware PWM outputs?" "hard real-time" is required for full precision. i bought a DS3231 RTC which should render the Adafruit 16-Channel 12-bit PWM/Servo Driver he is talking about obsolete. so if the pi takes it's time from the RTC i shouldn't have any problems right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Real-Time Clock (RTC) is completely irrelevant to the provision of PWM.

All an RTC does is tell a computer what time it is when it boots.  It's useful to time-stamp files and so that any on-screen clock displays current time.  It plays no part in the production of PWM.

The answer you link to is outdated as far as the Pi is concerned.  It reflects a reality in 2012.  Things have progressed since then.

For instance my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library provides servo/ESC suitable [PWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioPWM) on all gpios on the expansion header.  It also lets you control the two [hardware PWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioHardwarePWM) channels should you find a need for them.