# Analog/Digital IO pins

Tags: gpio

Can all of the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi 3 be used as both analog and digital pins? Are there any dedicated analog or digital pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Steve's answer. While all GPIO pins offer only digital input or output, PWM can be used (with very little external circuitry - a low-pass-filter) to at least output analog signals. The Pi has two dedicated hardware PWM pins and may further use the other GPIO pins for software PWM. Some of the interface libraries, such as [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) or [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/), support this feature. This is also the way the Raspberry Pi outputs analog audio.

Learn more: [Can I use the GPIO for pulse width modulation (PWM)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/298/19949)

Other than that analog input or output will require hardware add-ons such as *HATs* to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There are no analog pins on the Pi.