# Single PI with multiple connected devices using the same GPIO pin - need some sort of logic device?

Tags: gpio

I would like to connect a relay, a 4-digit display, and a light sensors to a single Pi Zero W.  I quickly realized that the relay and 4-digit display would conflict with one another because they are both using the GPIO18 pin.  I don't want the relay and display to have the GPIO18 signal all the time.

If I "split" the GPIO18 signal in two, what hardware could I use to allow the signal to pass through only if another connected pin is 'on' (please see image).[image: Blue signal is GPIO18 in image]

Thank you in advance - having a great time playing with this.

Comment: Why not just use another pin?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can do that.  I thought the GPIO18 was special sending PWM (pulse wave modulation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution you describe might not be the best one for your problem, the easy answer is that you need an [AND-gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate)

For example the [74AHCT1G08GW](http://www.nexperia.com/products/logic/gates/and-gates/74AHCT1G08GW.html) from NXP or the [SN74AHC1G08](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74AHC1G08) from TI should do.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!  You say this might not be the best solution for my problem, I'm curious what would be the best solution?  Thank you again.

Comment: Perhaps use SW PWM? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/298/can-i-use-the-gpio-for-pulse-width-modulation-pwm