# RPI GPIO Ports default on?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, boot, rpi.gpio, led

My LEDS connected to ports CE1 and CE0 are automatically on at startup. Is this normal? I have included a code that turns them all off when I run the script.

Comment: Highly related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32639/19949

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is normal.

GPIO 0-8 have their internal pulls to 3V3 enabled at boot.  That will allow enough current to flow to dimly light a LED.