# LED on breadboard lights up on boot

Tags: pi-3, led, breadboard

I have a setup like below:

[image]

The script is supposed to turn the led on, sleep and turn it off again. And the script does work.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# This script will turn on the LED for 1 second and turn it off again

# setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# disable warnings
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# set GPIO.OUT to pin 18
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

# turn on LED
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
# wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)
# turn off led
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

If I reboot the pi the led suddenly is on again and I wonder why. Is it because I am missing something important about the pi's functionality or am I making mistakes here? By the way the same behavior occurs with rgb leds too.

I also read up on `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` and it seems that the only difference between the modes `BCM` and `BOARD` are the number one uses when referring to pins, or might the mode be the issue?

Comment: I am a complete noob with the RPi hardware, but it just so happens that I might have read up on this very issue last night. As I understand it, the initial state of the GPIO pins on boot can fluctuate. A lot of people dealing with motor controls were particularly concerned about this. There is discussion about this on the [RPi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=35321) and jojopi's 12/31/16 reply might be helpful. I researched it far enough to discover [device tree overlays](http://int03.co.uk/blog/2015/01/11/raspberry-pi-gpio-states-at-boot-time/) but no further.

Comment: What happens if you set the pin back to INPUT at the very end of the script? Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee the state of the GPIO pins during the boot process; all sorts of things from the kernel configuration, device tree, modules etc can mess with this.

See [Why are some GPIO pins HIGH when the Raspberry Pi boots up?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32639/why-are-some-gpio-pins-high-when-the-raspberry-pi-boots-up)

You could run a script from /etc/rc.local to reset this pin on boot, as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md).

Answer (score 1):

Try to cleanup the GPIO pins to restore them to low state. Try the following code for [example](http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/09/using-gpio-of-raspberry-pi-to-blink-led.html):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time

PIN = 12

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# blinking function  
def blink(pin):
        GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)  
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)  
        time.sleep(1)  
        return

# to use Raspberry Pi board GPIO Board Numbering
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# set up GPIO output channel  
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.OUT)  

# blink GPIO18 10 times  
for i in range(0, 10):  
        blink(PIN)  
GPIO.cleanup()
```

> I have modified the code from the site a bit to match your
>   code's pin numbers.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using BOARD mode here?

Comment: @チーズパン I really prefer using BOARD mode for numbering to be generic on all versions of Raspberry Pi